# How can I use SiteMap more efficiently?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitemap, mvcsitemapprovider

So, in our website we are using `SiteMap`. For each request we render some menu and to do that we do `SiteMap.RootNode` in the helper function.

Now, when I have done the profiling of my website using **dotTrace**, I saw the `get_RootNode()` is taking lot's of time(around 70-75 millisecond). But we know that the `SiteMap` is static. So, I am thinking in somehow I will get the `SiteMap.RootNode` only once in `Application_Start` and will access that through out each request.

So, my questions are,

Is my approach correct? 
How should I do that?
Or is there any efficient way that I can use `SiteMap.RootNode`

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a custom SiteMap provider?  The default provider is cached/optimized so I have to assume you're loading from a database or something?

Comment: I am using mvcSiteMap provider. And I am not loading from database. I have just one Web.sitemap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have avoided sitemaps for exactly this reason.
They are ok up to a few hundred pages but beyond that performance will start to degrade.

I think they are meant to be a simple getting started type tool for smaller web sites or something.

I wrote my own cms and in theory if you are using a similar cms / app that structures the data in the same way you should be able to pull your menu listings from the db in less time by getting all children of the current page id / some form of similar context based query.

You can (as i am told) however break down your sitemaps in to smaller partial maps then pull the menu listings from those to increase performance.

If however your site has less than 500 pages I would question the coding ... is it a custom sitemap?
Is the provider waiting for resource locks or something?

Have you considered pulling the data using the xmldocument class instead? (just a thought)